# Translating CACLS commands to ICACLS

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

How this CACLS command would translate to ICACLS?

```
CACLS "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" /G "Network Service":R /E
```

My doubt is mainly with the parameter /E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of `icacls`, with `/grant` or `/deny` switches, is to edit the ACL.  You do not need to specify an edit operation explicitly as with `cacls`.

Using `icacls` to mirror your example:

```
icacls "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" /grant "Network Service":(R)
```

You can also use `/grant` and `/deny` in conjunction with `:r` to remove existing explicitly granted permissions.  Please see `icacls /?` for [full details](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919240).

**Edit:**

If you intend to call `icacls` from PS, quoting works differently.  Please try:

```
icacls 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config' /grant 'Network Service:(R)'
```

Comment: @jscott, the command is returning an error:
net user "Network Service"
The user name could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.

Invalid parameter "Network Service"
Looks like it can't find the user "Network Service".

Comment: @Norberto: The error you list is from the `NET` command, not `icacls`. I just copy/pasted my above command and tested it works.  Are you attempting to use this in a script/loop?

Comment: @jscott: In the previous attempt i used Powershell to execute the command, wich doesn't work. But in the command prompt it worked. Very weird.

Comment: @Norbert: Quoting works *slightly* different in PS. If you must use it in PS, I will update my answer.

Comment: @jscott: I'm unable to see what's the problem with the quoting in Powershell. I would appreciate if you help me in this one.